# SQL Server CASE statement with two conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, case, between

I have a sample table which has the helpdesk call centre data. In this table call logs and related stuffs are being stored. This table has a `call_no` and a `date_logged` column.

I am trying to use one case where I can get the total number of calls over a given time period.

Below is the sample code.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CALLS.DATE_LOGGED BETWEEN '2018/04/06' AND '2018/04/07' 
               THEN calls.CALL_NO END) AS "CALLS LOGGED YESTERDAY"
FROM 
    LOGGED_CALLS CALLS
```

This is giving me the total number of calls that are in my system, I do not want to use a where clause outside of this condition.

Let us assume that it is the 7th of April again and I want to get the calls logged from the day before

Comment: Strange I was always under the impression that NULLS were not counted.  What RDBMS is this?  Is there a reason you don't want to use a where clause?  a technical limitation other criteria you want to return that would be otherwise excluded?  using a where seems far simplest; if all you're after is a count.

Comment: How come you don't want to use a `where`? `select count(*) from calls where date_logged between '2018/04/06' AND '2018/04/07'` would work just fine.

Comment: if I start adding more columns to the query the where will affect all of them

Comment: if you don't want to use where clause this will impact your query performance. read the order of execution in sql server. Where clause will help you in performance.

Comment: How do either of those date values represent "yesterday"?  I suspect you are misinterpreting the results.

Comment: I have just edited my post, hopefully it explains the dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SUM instead of COUNT:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN CALLS.DATE_LOGGED BETWEEN '2018/04/06' AND '2018/04/07' 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "CALLS LOGGED YESTERDAY"

FROM LOGGED_CALLS CALLS
```

Comment: This should not change the result.  `COUNT()` only counts non-NULL values and without an `ELSE` clause, the non-matches are `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was under the impression that the behavior of case without a specified else wasn't consistent under older SQL versions.

Comment: . . I am not aware of any such behavior.